# Remove trailing / from list of links

Tags: python, python-3.x, trailing-slash, trailing

I have a list of URLs, and I am trying to remove the trailing '/' from all URLs in the list. I have tried all of these variations with no error message, but no removal of the /:

```
for link in url_list:
   if link.endswith('/'):
      url_list.append(link[:-1])

for link in url_list:
    if link.endswith('/'):
       link = link[:-1]

for link in url_list:
    link = link[:-1] if link.endswith('/') else link
```

After running these codes I `print(url_list)` and nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you show `url_list`? Your current first method (although not optimal) should work, but it adds the the exisiting list, did you mean to append to a new one?

Comment: It is a pretty long list so it wouldn't be feasible to list here.  The odd thing is that I created a new list with the same content and ran the original code again and it seems to have worked.  The main thing is that I want the change to remain when I write it to a csv

Answer (score 2):

You first for-loop almost works, although it appends the new formed urls to you existing ones instead of replacing.

A better approach would be to create a new list with list-comprehension and use `str.rstrip` to remove a trailing `/`.

### Code

```
url_list = ['googoo.com/foo/', 'wikipidoo.org/bar/', 'stachoverflaw.com/baz']

stripped_urls = [url.rstrip('/') for url in url_list]

print(stripped_urls)
```

### Output

```
['googoo.com/foo', 'wikipidoo.org/bar', 'stachoverflaw.com/baz']
```

Comment: `url_list.append(link[:-1])` works though (but dosen't create a new list of course)

Comment: Note that this works for urls that _don't_ end with a `'/'`, as well. I'd probably use `map` instead of a comprehension, though.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Yes! I was just adding the note since your example only shows true positives. Based on my reading of the question, I believe your code will work for OP's requirements. Nice answer.

Comment: @erip good point actually, I will add an url with no trailing /

Comment: `os.path.normpath` would be a possible (questionable) alternative

Comment: @Chris_Rands This will not work, an os using \ as separator will replace all / by \. I had the feeling there would be a caveat to this, there it is